# SQL Query to Show next date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I write a query which will return the next date.

Here is example, I want query to populate the Next_Date column

Thanks

```
Employee_ID    Date        Point       Next_Date
53             07/31/2015    1         12/02/2015   
53             12/02/2015    1         01/12/2016
53             01/12/2016    1         02/10/2016
53             02/10/2016    1
```

I used the following query but getting the Null

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 att.attend_date
FROM 
    Attendance att
WHERE 
    att.ID_Employee=att.ID_Employee and
    att.attend_date > att.attend_date
ORDER BY 
          att.attend_date ASC
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I wouldn't store that Next_Date values in the table, too high risk of data inconsistency when rows are added/deleted/updated. Instead create a view that always has consistent data! (Or manage by triggers.)

Comment: thanks all using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead should work, depending on which DB you are using.

```
select 
  employee_id, 
  date, 
  point,
  lead(date) over (partition by employee_id order by date) as next_date
from your_table
```

Comment: How about the next_date based on employee_ID e.g. I have more than one employees and I want to check their next day

Comment: Edited the query above.  If you partition by employee_id then it will only give you the next_date for the same employee_id.  For the last row for each employee_id, the next_date will be NULL.

Comment: Yes that is I want Thanks mo2, by the way I am mo too

Answer (score 0):

You need a column to specify the order since a table has no inherent order. It seems not to be ordered by the `Date`-column, otherwise your first two records would have the wrong `Next_Date` since they are in the past.

So i assume that you have a primary key to determine the order.

Then you can use this query(`TOP`presumes sql-server so must be changed in other rdbms):

```
UPDATE t SET Next_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Date 
                          FROM TableName t2
                          WHERE t2.ID > t.ID)
FROM TableName t
WHERE t.Next_Date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server you can use Row_Number to find the next row that matches your condition.

```
WITH assignmentsSubQuery as
(
    select row_number() over (partition by Employee_ID order by date desc)  as rowId, employee_id, date AS Next_Date
    from Assignments
)
UPDATE
    A 
set
    A.Next_Date = A2.Next_Date
from 
    Assignments A inner join 
    assignmentsSubQuery A1 on (A.employee_id = a1.Employee_ID and A.[Date] = A1.Next_Date) inner join 
    assignmentsSubQuery A2 on (A1.employee_id = a2.Employee_ID and A1.rowId = A2.rowId + 1)
```